# Mouse button mapping in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to optimize vim somehow. But really can't make any use of my additional buttons. My question is
"Is there a way to bind 4th / 5th mouse button to vim some action ?"

Comment: Are you using gvim or are you running vim in some terminal emulator?

Comment: Also, as well as melpomene's queries, it would be worth saying what operating system and what mouse you're using.

Comment: The mappable buttons are listed under `:help <MiddleRelease>`.

Comment: Start optimizing by weaning yourself off the mouse inside Vim. Learn the various (keyboard) navigation commands in and out instead.